Typescript 'Object is possibly undefined' when using map on array inside object
I have an array of objects, which contain also arrays which Im iterating through. I get the err 'Object is possibly undefined' and Im not sure how to solve it
const arr = {
  1: "something",
  2: "somethingelse",
...
};

export interface IData {
  someString?: string | undefined;
  items?: {
    name?: string | undefined;
    value?: string | undefined;
  }[];
}

const App = ({dataCollection}: IData[]) => {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
      {dataCollection.map((data) => (
          <div>
            {Object.entries(arr).map(([key]) => {
--> error comes from data(
              const filtered = data.items.find((d) => {
                return d.name === key;
              });
              return (
                <h1>{filtered?.value}</h1>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};


What is unclear about the error message? data.items is possibly undefined because it is defined as optional in the type.

shouldnt then "data?.items.find..." remove the error?

No, but data.items?.find should.

Before you map any array which may be undefined to the compiler (anything which is not static), always check if it exists
For Example:
const staticArray = ["Static", "Array"]; 
const dynamicArray = fetchDynamicArray(); 

staticArray.map((item) => {...}) // Correct

dynamicArray && dynamicArray.map((item) => {...}) // Check for undefined

